# Why use defer with new promise

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred

Never used `defer` before but my agent asked me to use `defer` with promises.

In mozilla defer page, it says `defer` is obsolete and should not be used anymore. But in the same page there is example.

My question is, why to use `defer` with promise? Whats it's advantage for code below, only write less code? I should define a new promise instead of that?

```
export function defer () {
  const deferred = {}
  deferred.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deferred.resolve = resolve
    deferred.reject = reject
  })

  return deferred
}
```

And the code that is using it:

```
export async function waitForPredicate (peer, path, predicate, cancelToken) {
  const deferredFetcher = defer()
  ...
  let result = predicate(data)
  if (result) {
    deferredFetcher.resolve(result)
  }
})
```

Comment: Who's your "agent"?

Comment: I can not give my agent name but its a big one. Actually I am not asking difference between defer().promise and Promise. I am asking why use an old style defer for a promise.

Comment: I am asking you to change your agent - he does not understand promises :-)

Comment: I dont think so, he is a master on that. I did not wrote whole story. There is a promise race and one of them is timeout promise. also there is tagPromise function. There must be some reason people still use it.

Answer (score 0):

Before the ES6 Promise pattern was standardized, deferreds were a pattern/view into a `Promise` that can modify the state.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6 standardisation.

Comment: @Bergi i'm trying to give *historical* context here.

Comment: Sometimes defer needed when you use them in other class and you dont need use promise. I mean you already have a new promise in defer object and you can use use whenever you want, and you can also use resolve and reject as parameters inside the code.